# How to add different or second collection Id to UserState?

Tags: c#, botframework

Can i access a different collection Id in my cosmos db using userstate?
Thanks!

[image]

```
    var userStateStorage = new CosmosDbStorage(new CosmosDbStorageOptions
    {
        AuthKey = CosmosDBKey,
        CollectionId = CosmosDBCollectionNameUser,
        CosmosDBEndpoint = new Uri(CosmosServiceEndpoint),
        DatabaseId = CosmosDBDatabaseName,
    });

    var userState = new UserState(userStateStorage);

    services.AddSingleton(userState);
```

**UPDATE:**
I created it like this but when i check cosmos, my reminder collection is being populated the by another class model(which i use on the other userState)

On startup:

```
            var reminderStorage = new CosmosDbStorage(new CosmosDbStorageOptions
            {
                AuthKey = CosmosDBKey,
                CollectionId = CosmosDBCollectionNameReminder,
                CosmosDBEndpoint = new Uri(CosmosServiceEndpoint),
                DatabaseId = CosmosDBDatabaseName,
            });

            var reminderState = new UserState(reminderStorage);

            services.AddSingleton(reminderState);
```

On the dialog:

```
 public class ReminderDialog : ComponentDialog
{
    private readonly IStatePropertyAccessor<BasicUserReminders> _reminderAccessor;

    public ReminderDialog(UserState userState)
        : base(nameof(ReminderDialog))
    {
        _reminderAccessor = userState.CreateProperty<BasicUserReminders>("Reminders");

        WaterfallStep[] waterfallSteps = new WaterfallStep[]
        {
            FirstStepAsync,
            SecondStepAsync,
        };
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), waterfallSteps));
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> FirstStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var reminderState = await _reminderAccessor.GetAsync(stepContext.Context, () => new BasicUserReminders(), cancellationToken);

        var reminder = new BasicUserReminders.Reminder
        {
            Subject = "to drink water",
            Days = new List<int> { 4, 3, 2 },
            Frequency = "everyday"
        };

        reminderState.Reminders.Add(reminder);

        return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the format of our previous Q&As, I'm going to post a non-code answer so you can't copy/paste . Feel free to comment if you need clarification, but update your question with additional code.

It's not so much about what `UserState` can or can't access within your Cosmos DB. It's more about what `userStateStorage` can access. As you can see, it's an instance of `CosmosDbStorage`, which is coded to only interact with a *single* collection.

So, no, `UserState` cannot access other collections and neither can `userStateStorage`. However, you can create additional/separate `CosmosDbStorage` instances that access other collections and also dependency-inject them.

### First Reply

I'm guessing you used `services.AddSingleton(user/reminderState)` for each one, so you've got two `UserState`s injected in Startup, right? So, when you call `public ReminderDialog(UserState userState)`, how does it know which one to use?

You've got to DI a different way. [Here's a big hint](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/1705#issuecomment-522174740)

Comment: Haha i updated my question now Sir Richardson. By the way at first when i created a new collection on my azure cosmos DB but getting the cross partition error so i deleted that collection and let bot framework create it for me and the error is gone.

Comment: @user10860402 See **First Reply**. Your PartitionKey issue likely has something to do with [this](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5467)

Comment: Sorry i'm still a little lost Sir Richardson. Yes i created two userstate in startup(is that correct?) and yes i thought of that too that how will UserState know which one to use. Unfortunately i still can't understand even with the link. I will try again tomorrow.

Comment: @user10860402 Bigger hint: Put the accessors in a separate/new class and DI the new class. It may help to read mutanttech's issue and then see the comment that I linked to.

Comment: Thanks! I will try again on Monday.

Comment: @user10860402 Were you able to get this working with my answer? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Comment: Sorry i was about to comment here. Been very busy and have not tried this again yet. Please give me 2 days thanks!

Comment: @user10860402 No problem being busy. I'm going to close this on my support tracker (since time to close tickets is monitored), so I won't be checking this as much. Be sure to "@.mention" me if you have updates and I'll be sure to respond